# How to sort files in file manager by track?

Tags: filemanager, sort

I'm recently want to try if any chance i can sort my files in file manager by track number especially for music files.
Please help ?

Answer (score 2):

It takes a long time to do properly, but I'd strongly suggest getting a decent file-naming convention sorted out. Something *like*:

```
{{Album}} {{Disc}}{{Track#}} {{Artist}} - {{Track Title}}
```

There are a hundred thoussand variants on this, some using directories, some not, but the important thing is you're making it sortable at a very simple filename level. Consistently.

Of course doing all that manually is overwhelming for most people by the time they decide it's a problem. There are good tools that exist out there. My favourite by a mile is [MusicBrainz Picard](https://picard.musicbrainz.org/). It's free and uses MusicBrainz' huge database for correcting tags and then setting filenames (to whatever scheme *you* want).

Even so, you're going to have to input every album you own into that.
It's going to take time... But speaking as somebody who has been through this process twice now (for ~40,000 tracks): it's worth it.

Comment: Yeah, MusicBrainz and Picard are great. +1

Answer (score 1):

Using the Nautilus extension `nautilus-columns`

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nautilus-columns
nautilus -q
```

Enable the columns in Nautilus Preferences

[image]

[image]